# Making "Mark all" button

Tags: javascript, html

How can i make a "Mark all" link that, marks all checkboxes there is inside a td:

```
<td style="padding-right:4px;padding:4px;" class="alternating">
    <input name="cbPick" type="checkbox" value="88156144" />
</td>
```

Don't know what language you write this in.. JavaScript?

Comment: Pretty much your only choice is going to be Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
function checkAll(value, arr) {
 $(arr).each(function () {
  if (value) {
   $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
  }
  else {
   $(this).removeAttr('checked');
  }
 });
}
```

Usage:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check' /><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="check' /><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="check' /><br />
<a href="#" onclick="checkAll(true, $('.check'))">Mark all</a>
```

P.S.

Yes, it requires jQuery. OMG OMG!!

Comment: @Breezer: Yes it requires jQuery. jQuery is like .NET - remarks like "it requires additional software` are vacancy from Stone Age!!

Comment: +1: If you're already using JavaScript, it isn't exactly like you're taking a huge maintenance hit or require some outlandish learning curve to add in jQuery.

Comment: @jwiscarson: Thanks for the encouragement! In addition I want to say that jQuery is awesome and JS without it - is plain hell pain. True story.

Answer (score 2):

It would be in Javascript. 
You would be using the DOM API.

```
function markAll() {
  var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for(var index in tds) {
    var innerNode = tds[index].firstChild;
    if(innerNode.tagName == 'input' && innerNode.attributes.type="checkbox")
      innerNode.checked = true;
  }
}
```

You'd then need to make sure that the onClicked handler for the mark all link references this function. This code also assumes that where the tickbox is inside the TD's, it is the first child - otherwise this code would be more complicated.

Reference info:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_checkbox.asp

Comment: This solution also does not require any additional libraries - I think abatishchev's solution requires Jquery - it looks like JQuery to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be javascript, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectAll(x) {
  for(var i=0,l=x.form.length; i<l; i++){
    if(x.form[i].type == 'checkbox' && x.form[i].name != 'selectAll'){
      x.form[i].checked=x.form[i].checked?false:true
    }
  }
}
</script>

<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="selectAll" onclick="selectAll(this)" /> (Select all)<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="a" /> (A)<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="b" /> (B)<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="c" /> (C)<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="d" /> (D)<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="e" /> (E)
</form>
```

Comment: If you're caching the length of `x.form`, you might as well cache `x.form` and `x.form[i]` as well. I think `x.form[i].checked=x.form[i].checked?false:true` should be `x.form[i].checked=x.checked`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah javascript is the way to go
here is a link for a way to do it

http://www.shiningstar.net/articles/articles/javascript/checkboxes.asp